# How do I speed up zigzag merge on development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am just starting to take advantage of zigzag merge to reduce # of indexes, and am testing on my dev machine. I am finding it to be extremely slow, even when the # of results in each query is not large.

For example:
1) one query with 25 results takes ~5 seconds
2) two queries with 25 results each, and 25 merged takes 15 seconds
3) three queries with 25 results each, and 1 merged takes 100 seconds!

Is this expected???

Comment: dev server emulates the datastore with a sql db. Try it on production before drawing any conclusions about speed etc.

Comment: You definitely can't make any conclusions about performance when you use the dev server.

Comment: It works fine in production, but I can't even do basic testing locally! Something is not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a bug in the development server. A change was made to make some merge joins faster, but unfortunately made other ones significantly slower. There is an [issue tracking this bug here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10845). I would recommend using the 1.9.2 dev appserver for testing until this is fixed, or if you feel comfortable update the development server code as seen in the issue.

Comment: Wow! That change is like night and day! You're talking about 100 seconds to 800 milliseconds. Thank you!

Comment: Yup -- it's unfortunately because the fix/bug also made several queries do the exact opposite! There is a fix in the 1.9.5 release that should make the query planner happier and have everything running faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. Do you have any 1.9.5 code I can paste now into datastore_sql_stub.py to fix all queries?

Comment: Hi Jacob - the basic issue is that (from what I can tell) SQLite does not run any stats analysis until you explicitly ask for it, which can lead to the wrong indexes getting used in the query. Try adding the following line in datastore_sqlite_stub.py in the __Init method (after the PRAGMA statement): `self.__connection.execute('ANALYZE')`. Note that this will only make queries better if you put your data, restart the development server, then run your queries. However, it's a start.

Comment: Hi Patrick - I tried the ANALYZE statement, but both startup and queries are running really slow. When I remove the statement, everything works fast.

Comment: Hi Jacob -- thank you for the feedback. Would you be willing to upload your sqlite database in a production issue here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

Comment: Make sure the ticket is filed as a "production issue". Then it will not be public.

Comment: Here's the issue link:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10859